# How to change the sliderInput knob (thumb) color in shiny?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, slider

I am trying to change the sliderInput knob/thumb color. Checked online and I saw some comments about using .irs-slider. However, it does not work for me in the following code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(".js-irs-0 .irs-single, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar, .js-irs-0 .irs-slider {background: red}")),

  sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1",min = 0.1, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.05),

)
server <- function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

This codes changed the color of everything except for the knob. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

UPDATE: Thanks to @Domingo for his answer. The following code will change the knob too. However, when I click on the knob to move it, it turns to white color. How can I change the knob color on click to a different color (not red) e.g. black?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      ".js-irs-0 .irs-single, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-bar, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-handle
       {
          background: red;
       }
      ")),
  
  sliderInput("slider1", 
              "Slider 1",
              min = 0.1, 
              max = 1, 
              value = 0.4, 
              step = 0.05),
  
)
server <- function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `.irs-handle` class to your style to change the css of the knob:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      ".js-irs-0 .irs-single, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-bar, 
       .js-irs-0 .irs-slider 
       {
          background: red;
       }
      .irs-handle {
          background: cyan !important;
      }
      .irs-handle:active {
          background: green !important;
      }
      ")),
  
  sliderInput("slider1", 
              "Slider 1",
              min = 0.1, 
              max = 1, 
              value = 0.4, 
              step = 0.05),
  
)
server <- function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Domingo for the answer. It did the job for me. By chance do you also know how to change the color of the knob/handle when we click on it to move it? it turns to white at this time and I would like to change that. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You can add an css part `.irs-handle:active {background: green!important; }`, with `:active` you tell your knob to be green, i changed that in my answer as well

Comment: Thanks @Domingo. I just accepted your answer.